# I am trying to use classes with a dictionary with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
class student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, year):
        self.name, self.age, self.year = name, age, year
        self.grades=[]
        self.grade={}
        print(name,'-------->','Age:',age,'','Year:',year)

    def set_grades(self,score):
        self.grades.append(score)
    def get_grades(self):
        return self.grades
    def average(self):
        return sum(self.grades)/len(self.grades)
    def topgrade(self,other):
        return max(self.average(),other.average())


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)+'--'+' Grades:'+str(self.grades)+'---Class average:'+str(self.average())

    def dicts(self):
        return grade[self.name]=self.grades


todd=student('Todd', 43, 4)
leah=student('Leah', 38,3)
```

When I run the code I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\toddb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\toddb\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/toddb/Desktop/student.py", line 32
    return grade[self.name]=self.grades
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried to do this several ways. Am I confined to just using a list?

Comment: Change `return grade[self.name]=self.grades` to `return grade[self.name]`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Wouldn't it need to be `self.grade`?

Comment: @mbomb007: you're right! that too :P

Answer (score 3):

That's because you can't return the result of an assignment in Python:

```
class Test(object):
    pass

a = Test()
somevariable = a.attr = 10
```

works - but as soon as you want to return it:

```
def func():
    a = Test()
    return a.testattr = 10

>>> func()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

or even easier:

```
def func():
    return a = 0

>>> func()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So you need to split the assignment and the return:

```
def dicts(self):
    grade[self.name]=self.grades
    return grade
```

Note that this will raise a `NameError` when you try to call this function (except you have a global variable with the name `grade`). But you probably meant `self.grade`:

```
def dicts(self):
    self.grade[self.name]=self.grades
    return self.grade
```

This in turn will permanently alter your `self.grade` dictionary. If you don't want that you can create a copy before assignment:

```
def dicts(self):
    grade = self.grade.copy()
    grade[self.name]=self.grades
    return grade
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it the same `grade` dictionary declared in `__init__`?? Then it should say `self.grade[self.name]=self.grades`, otherwise do this `grades = {}` inside the `dicts` method before using `grades` as a dictionary